# Determine if a certain File is process by a project that uses Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

Good day!  I am currently developing a website using Google Drive API.  However, I am wondering if is it possible to know if a certain file is created/uploaded/shared by the project using an App Id.  I was thinking if it is belong to the attributes of a file.  But, when i checked, it seems that, there's no such thing.

What I am trying to do, is to filter the files' shared by the other user to the owner of the account using my web site. Is it possible? Any suggestions on how to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

File metadata doesn't contain this information unfortunatelly, therefore you can't know if some file was created by your app or not. But FYI Google store it somewhere, if you will try to upload somefile without providing its content type (*** / ***) and after that try to open this file through browser you will see the message:

*No preview available
This item was created with YourAppName, a Google Drive app.
Download this file or use one of the apps you have installed to open it.*